# Is .put() in .getOrDefault() computed every time?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Map<String, Ob> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] arr = {"a", "a", "c", "c"};

int count = 1;
for (String a: arr) {
    System.out.println("putting \"" + a + "\" in map");
    System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(a, map.put(a, new Ob(a + "" + count++))));
    System.out.println("map: " + map);
}
```

`Ob` is a very simple class:

```
class Ob {
    String o;
    Ob (String message) { o = message; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return o; }
}
```

Prints:

```
putting "a" in map
a1
map: {a=a1}
putting "a" in map
a2                        
map: {a=a2}                     -> Why is the value replaced?
putting "c" in map
c3
map: {a=a2, c=c3}
putting "c" in map
c4
map: {a=a2, c=c4}               -> Why is the value replaced?
```

I was thinking for the second `a` it would simply fetch the value `a1` and return because `a` already exists in the map. But it created the object in `.put()`.

It looks like the `default` in `getOrDefault` computed even if key exists. How can I write this concisely without creating new objects when the key already exists?

I can write it with an `if/else`, surely, but I want to see if the current approach can be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `getOrDefault` is evaluated before the method is called (as is always the case with expressions used as method parameters), so it has to happen every time.

`Map` has a method [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) that does what you want, here:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(a, k -> new Ob(k + "" + count++));
```

If `a` is in the map, its value will be returned. If it isn't, it will be passed to the lambda (as parameter `k`, here) and the value of the lambda will be inserted into the map under key `a` and also returned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It must be in order to create the value actually passed in to be returned as default value if  the value is not present.

You may want to rethink your logic.